# What is "private output" mode in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I open a notebook and get this banner at the very top of the window:

> This notebook is open with private outputs. Outputs will not be saved.
>   You can disable this in Notebook settings.

What does this mean in regards to how I can use the notebook?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When private outputs are enabled, the content that you see in code cell outputs is not saved when you download or save the notebook. Outputs are also dropped if you make a copy in Drive.

To adjust the private output settings, select the notebook settings from the edit menu.

[image]

Then, uncheck the 'Omit code cell output when saving this notebook' checkbox.

[image]

(It's common for many example or tutorial notebooks to be saved with private outputs to make it easier to see which cells you've executed and which are remaining.)

Comment: So, if we uncheck the 'Omit code cell output when saving this notebook' checkbox, every time, I'll reopen the notebook, I'll be able to see the output of all the executed cells

Comment: I've unchecked it, still nothing